# How to restructure data frame in R

Tags: r

For example, given the below data structure

```
v1 = c("DL1",    "", "DL3", "DL4",   "") 
v2 = c("DL1", "DL2", "DL3",    "","DL5") 
v3 = c("DL1", "DL2", "DL3",    "","DL5") 
v4 = c(   "",    "", "DL3",    "","DL5") 
v5 = c(   "",    "",    "",    "","DL5") 
data1 = rbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)
```

I want to generate

```
vt1 = c("DL1", "DL3", "DL4",    "","") 
vt2 = c("DL1", "DL2", "DL3", "DL5","") 
vt3 = c("DL1", "DL2", "DL3", "DL5","") 
vt4 = c("DL3",   "" ,    "",    "","") 
vt5 = c("DL5",   "" ,    "",    "","")  
data2 = rbind(vt1,vt2,vt3,vt4,vt5)
```

Comment: Can you format the dataframe structure please? This hard to read for anyone who wants to answer.

Comment: Could you check `v4` and `vt4`?

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution is this.

```
m <- data.frame(t(rbind(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
mx <- t(sapply(m, function(x) {
  s <- x[x != ""]
  e <- 5 - length(s)
  return(c(s, rep("", e)))
}))
```

To get the rownames:

```
rownames(mx) <- gsub("v", "vt", rownames(mx))
```

**Produces**

```
> mx
    [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]
vt1 "DL1" "DL3" "DL4" ""    ""  
vt2 "DL1" "DL2" "DL3" "DL5" ""  
vt3 "DL1" "DL2" "DL3" "DL5" ""  
vt4 "DL3" "DL5" ""    ""    ""  
vt5 "DL5" ""    ""    ""    ""
```